# Refer to other classes java

Tags: java, class

I am to create an animal shop. I have a bunch of cat and dog names, a max age and cage number. Out of this I need this info here:

```
public int findCageNr(String name){
    //CageNr exists in class CreateAnimalshop and should be found with one of the names entered here.
}
public int amountAnimals(){
    //To add all animals from CreateAnimalshop together
}
public int amountDogs(){
    //Only dogs
}

public int amountCats(){
    //Only cats
}

public String whichAnimal( Dyr d){
    //Is it dog or cat?
}

public double averageAgeDogs(){

}
public double averageAgeCats(){

}
public double averageAgeAnimals(){

}
```

My main problem here is that I have this info in other classes but I do now need to collect it to give some info back (and calculate the average age etc). My class for cats is called "Cat" and my class for dogs is called "Dog"(they are extentions of a class "Animals"). All animals is saved in "myDataBase" as a vector .

How do I sort out if it is a cat or a dog? 
How do I call upon createAnimalshop to get the other info here? Or the myDataBase values in this class.

I tried to call it by entering this

```
public class AnimalShop {
private Vector<Animals> myDataBase;

public AnimalShop() {
   CreateAnimalshop butikk = new CreateAnimalshop();
   myDataBase = butikk.getMyDataBase();
   start();

}
```

Comment: what exactly is this supposed to do? public AnimalShop() {
   CreateAnimalshop butikk = new CreateAnimalshop();

Comment: It is supposed to write the info out like println amountCats etc

Comment: You probably don't want to be using `Vector`. Usually `ArrayList` is more appropriate.

Comment: @Katholyn I can honestly not think of a single purpose for the existence of CreateAnimalShop if it's called within the AnimalShop constructor.

Comment: @Stultuske I misunderstood your question. See the new code I added. It should get some info from there.